# Affix sidebar overlays Angular Material flex row

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, angular-material

The idea is to make sidebar stay at the top when screen size is smaller than 1200px or so. When screen size is bigger than 1200px - affix sidebar should be fixed as user scrolls down a page. At the moment affix sidebar `<div class="side-tool-panel" layout="column">` interferes with neighbour container  `<div class="content-wrapper" layout="row" layout-wrap>`. How to make `<div class="content-wrapper" layout="row" layout-wrap>` to shift automatically and make up the room for `<div class="side-tool-panel" layout="column">`?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/ResilientJoe/pen/GZdJze)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [layout system](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) of Angular Material to do that. Try this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="" layout="column" layout-gt-md="row" layout-wrap>
    <div class="side-tool-panel" layout="column" flex-gt-md="15"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper" layout="row" layout-wrap flex-gt-md="85"></div>
</div>
```

In this code I use `layout-gt-md` which `width >= 1280px`. Then, I use `flex-gt-md` in 2 children `div`. [Here](http://codepen.io/DieuNQ/pen/MyGezV)

Hope this help.

Comment: After width of device screen drops below 1200px, then the minimal number of md-card stays **always 2**. I think it needs to display only one `md-card` per line as screen is less than 900px.... I expect it to handle it automatically. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/DieuNQ/pen/MyGezV?editors=1000#anon-login). Please read more about [layout system](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) of Angular Material